# Extending ObjC generic in Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics, parameters, swift3

Swift 3 comes with [SE-0057](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0057-importing-objc-generics.md) implemented that, among other things, means that:

> By default, extensions of parameterized Objective-C classes cannot reference the type parameters in any way. For example:
>
> ```
> extension MySet {
>   func someNewMethod(x: T) { ... } // error: cannot use `T`.
> }
> ```

... where `MySet` is declared in ObjC as `@interface MySet<T : id<NSCopying>> : NSObject`.

All that is clear (and there is some sort of workaround possible even).  However, the following does not compile despite that I am not using any type parameters from ObjC class that I am trying to extend.  I am only using another unrelated Swift class as a return parameter to the extension method:

```
class Foo { }
struct Bar { }

extension MySet {
    func foo() -> Foo { return Foo() } // Both produce: Extension of a generic
    func bar() -> Bar { return Bar() } // Objective-C class cannot access the 
}                                      // class's generic parameters at runtime
```

Is this a bug?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Filed a bug for time being: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2708

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @Marin, I did not really solve it.  The bug still stands open.  I faced it with Rx-Swift extensions I was trying to inject into Parse classes, so I had to stop using them.

Comment: that's sad ! I don't like this

Answer (score 2):

### Details

xCode 8.3.1, swift 3.1

### Sample

> MySet.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MySet<T : id<NSCopying>> : NSObject

@end

typedef struct ObjCStruct
{
    __unsafe_unretained NSString* str;
    int num;
} ObjCStruct;
```

> MySet.m

```
#import "MySet.h"

@implementation MySet

@end
```

> MySetExtension.swift

```
import Foundation

class Foo: NSObject {
    var str = "Foo"
    var num = 1
}

extension ObjCStruct {

    init() {
        num = 2
        str = Unmanaged.passRetained("ObjCStruct")
    }
}

extension MySet {
    func foo() -> Foo { return Foo() }
    func bar() -> ObjCStruct { return ObjCStruct() }
}
```

> Bridging-Header

```
#import "MySet.h"
```

### Usage

```
NSLog(@"%@", [set foo].str);
NSLog(@"%@", [set bar].str);
```